# Help me understand the structure of the question

Tags: questions

> In which of the following does the author of the passage reinforce his
>   criticism of responses such as Isaacs’ to Raisin in the Sun?
>
> ```
> A The statement that Hansberry is “loyal” to the American dream.
> B The description of Hansberry’s concern for Black Americans as “intense”.
> ...
> ```

What does the question mean? What does "In which" mean?

How do I insert the answer into the question, and make the question a statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read it like this:

"In which of the following [statements] does the author of the passage reinforce his criticism of responses (such as Isaacs’ response) to Raisin in the Sun?"

There is a play called Raisin in the Sun. Some people have responded to this play. One such person was Isaac. The author of the passage has criticized these responses. He reinforced his criticism of the responses (that is, he has made his criticism stronger) by saying certain things. In which of A, B, C, ... did he reinforce his criticism?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, but I'm still a little confused on the last sentense, __In which of A, B, C, ... did he reinforce his criticism?__ Does it mean How did he reinforce his criticism, and A, B, C are the means to reinforce? Or does it mean A, B, C are his criticism, but he only reinforced one of them, and the question asks me to pick one that he reinforced?

Comment: @QiqiGu,  "In which of A, B, C, ... did he reinforce his criticism". Read that like this: "He reinforced his criticism in one or more of A, B, C. Which ones?" A, B, C are the means to reinforce, or at least one or more of them are. You have to say which one or ones.